# How to authenticate using OAuth2 using Logic App

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-logic-apps

I have an Restful API which requires OAuth2 in order to get the token.

```
$username = 'A'
$password = 'B'
$ClientID = "C"
$client_secret = "D"
$RestEndpoint = 'https://oauth2/token'
```

I am trying to create a Logic Apps. But I am not sure if Logic Apps can handle OAuth2 or if there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure AD then you should be able to follow the these instructions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-custom-api-authentication#part-3-populate-the-authorization-section-in-your-logic-app

Part 3 has the specific configuration within your Logic App:

```html
Part 3: Populate the Authorization section in the Logic app

In the Authorization section of the HTTP action: {"tenant":"<<tenantId>>", "audience":"<<clientID from Part 2>>", "clientId":"<<clientID from Part 1>>","secret": "<<Password or Key from Part 1>>","type":"ActiveDirectoryOAuth" }
```